# how to split and concatenate in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am passing in a string into a stored procedure to be used in a select statement using dynamic sql:

```
@groups as nvarchar(1000) = 'group1,group10,group8'
```

I might just pass in string of numbers, eg, '1,2,3,4'

I want to split these values and then concatenate them so that they end up in the following manner :

```
'rmc.group1,rmc.group10,rmc.group8'
```

Comment: i might just pass in string of numbers, eg, '1,2,3,4'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @groups nvarchar(1000) ='group1,group10,group8'

set @groups = 'rmc.' + replace(@groups, ',', ',rmc.')
select @groups
```

Result:

```
rmc.group1,rmc.group10,rmc.group8
```

Comment: @Parado it will work because he concate 'rmc' to replaced string

Comment: @Parado `'rmc.' + replace(@groups, ',', ',rmc.')` see he concate rmc. to for  first element in replaced string..

Answer (score 4):

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42eb9/2)

```
Select Replace('group1,group10,group8','group','rmc.group')
```

Comment: @Parado thanks...why u remove yours ...it same and you are faster than me too

Comment: @Parado thats not gud you are faster than me.....there is nothing bad in editing answer...

Comment: but you didnt copied my answer you answered me 14 seconds before undelete your answer i will mention in comment there too

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @groups nvarchar(1000) = 'group1,group10,group8'

SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ',rmc.' + t
    FROM (
          SELECT t = t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')
          FROM (
               SELECT ID = CAST ('<t>' + REPLACE(@groups, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
          ) r 
          CROSS APPLY ID.nodes ('/t') t(c)
    ) t
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1,1, '')
```

Output -

```
------------------------------------
rmc.group1,rmc.group10,rmc.group8
```

Comment: I think the best solution - `REPLACE`

Comment: @Devart still try to understand how u do it really intresting